# Blank Concept map

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to make for university, blank concept maps, I have found a PDF, but it does not fit very well for me, because I need 3 notes at the bottom and at the top, and two at the side, I am interested if there is a package, which enables me to generate my own concept map. [image]

Comment: The tcolorbox poster capabilities could do this but it's probably quite complex https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/raw/master/doc/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox-tutorial-poster.pdf

Comment: Do they need placed on a circle? Three at the top, three at the bottom and one to each side would be a matrix. Otherwise, the easiest would be the `circular` graph drawing library which will need LuaLaTeX. Maybe a `forest` solution is possible.

Comment: No it would be nice, if it is all centered out. The circle could be also a box indsted!

Answer (score 2):

A simple example with `tcbposter` to start.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcbposter}[%
    coverage = spread,
    poster = {columns=3, rows=3}
]
\posterbox[title=A]{name=A, column=1, row = 1}{First idea}
\posterbox[title=B, colback=green!30]{name=B, column=2, row = 1}{Second idea}
\posterbox[title=C]{name=C, column=3, row = 1}{Third idea}
\posterbox[title=D]{name=D, column=1, row=2}{Fourth idea}
\posterbox[title=E]{name=E, column=3, row=2}{Fifth idea}
\posterbox[title=F]{name=F, column=1, row =3}{Sixth idea}
\posterbox[title=G]{name=G, column=2, row =3}{Seventh idea}
\posterbox[title=H]{name=H, column=3, row = 3}{Eigth idea}
\node[circle, minimum size=5cm, fill=red!30] (origin) at (TCBPOSTER@poster.center) {Origin};
\foreach \i in {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H}
 \draw[->, line width=1mm, shorten >=2mm, shorten <=2mm] (origin) -- (TCBPOSTER@\i);
\end{tcbposter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what i needed thank you so much, I adjusted it for my needings.